# Remove number from string with sscanf?

Tags: c

I have a string that is codified and I want to convert back , for example if I have 1 in the string it represents that in my struct I will have `e.nums_lins=1`, etc.

So I want to read the first element and then eliminate from the string, but have been trying with sscanf but no progress. Why this does not work?

```
  int x ;
  sscanf(argumentos, "%d", &x) //argumentos is the initial string
  printf ("%d",x); //1st element

  printf ("\n");

  print (argumentos); // rest of the string
```

Comment: `sscanf()` doesn't modify the string it operates on. You might be looking for something like `strtok()` with `atoi()` or `strtol()`.

Comment: Please not encourage newbies to use `atoi`

Comment: *Argumentos, the pirate's freshmaker!*

Comment: @EdHeal why? `atoi` is safe, good performant function. Personally, I'm against to use sscanf in very simple context, it overkill

Comment: Pass some random characters to `atoi` . It will not spot an error in the input.

Comment: Put wrong pointer into `sscanf`. This is massive and non checked error.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using the `%n` format specifier. It will store the number of characters scanned so far from the input. You can use that to offset past what has already been parsed from your input string.

```
  int x, n;
  sscanf(argumentos, "%d%n", &x, &n);
  printf("%d\n", x);    
  printf("%s", argumentos + n); // rest of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a string like

```
numlins1
```

which indicates that `e.nums_lins` should be set to 1.

If that's it then you want something like

```
sscanf(argumentos, "numlins%d", &e.nums_lins);
```

Here I assume that `argumentos` contains the string `"numlins1"`.  `scanf` will skip over the constant string `numlins`, then parse digits and asign the resulting number to `e.nums_lins`.

(I'm not sure what you were trying to do when you "printed the rest of the string" at the end, though.)